# (Flex & actionscript 3) convert result in datagrid control to json data

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder

i want to convert the result in spark datagrid cotrol to json data

i'm using actionscript 3 and Flex

this is my datagrid :

```
<s:DataGrid id="_gridcentre" left="5" right="5" top="5" bottom="5"
                                borderVisible="true" dataProvider="{GetCentreResult.lastResult}"
                                fontSize="11">
    <s:columns>
    <s:ArrayList>
        <s:GridColumn visible="false" dataField="Codecentre"headerText="Code"/>
        <s:GridColumn dataField="Nomcentre" headerText="Nom Centre"/>
        <s:GridColumn dataField="Typecentre" headerText="Type Centre"/>
        <s:GridColumn dataField="Milieurecepteur" headerText="Milieu Récepteur"/>
    </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

i did this code, but it not working :

```
var result:Object = _gridcentre.dataProvider as Object;
var myJson:String = JSON.stringify(result);
```

i can read my objects, when i iterate my object  < result > like this :

```
for each (var item:Centre in result) 
{
Alert.show(item.Codecentre.toString());
}
```

thanks for help

Comment: What does your `dataProvider` look like?

Comment: The data provider consists of a list of objects called items. Each item corresponds to one row of the DataGrid control.
the datagrid display result, i want just to get this result displayed in this grid and convert it to json

Comment: What are you getting for myJson vs. what are you expecting?  The code looks like it should work.

Comment: the JSON.stringify(result) don't work, i don't know how to get error in flash builder

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question.  After reading your question and comments, I still can't tell what's not working for you, other than you want something different to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataprovider is usually an instance of a array alike class.
Most likely spark's ArrayList or ArrayCollection class instance, which means that You can try **toArray()** method, which will return the raw objects contaned into, or if this fail - try to find the type of the data provider and invoke it's appropriate method to convert contained objects into   array or some other structure which you can iterate trough.

Answer (score 0):

h1! GetCentreResult.lastResult -> typeof() ?

Comment: the problem is not here, the GetCentreResult.lastResult is used to supply the datagrid cotroler.
i just want to convert the result displayed in my datagrid control to JSON, thats all

Comment: but GetCentreResult.lastResult is the dataprovider for the datagrid, so isn't it the same thing? because JSON might not work if it's an ArrayList for example

Comment: the dataprovider is IList
i make a cast before as ArrayCollection or Object or ArrayCollection but nothing works